# Tangent Space of 3-Sphere at a point P

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, tangent-spaces

Say I have a four variable function $S^3$ that is

$x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1$

and I want to find the tangent space at a given point P = (0,0,0,1). So far I have approached the problem by allowing for a function $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t),w(t))$ which belongs to $S^3$ such that we have

$x(t)^2+y(t)^2+z(t)^2+w(t)^2=1$

Now I am confused as to how the derivative of such a function, $\gamma(t)$, can be evaluated to be

$\gamma'(t)=2xx'+2yy'+2zz'+2ww'$

and how we know that $x(0)=y(0)=z(0)=0$ and that $w(0)=1$ so therefore $w'(0)=1$. From this it is said that apparently the set of vectors of the form $(a,b,c,0)$ make up the tangent plane at the point $P$.

Comment: You can also approach it from the perspective of gradients if you'd like to avoid a parameterization.  If $f(x,y,z,w) = x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$, then your sphere is simply a level surface of $f$, namely $f(x,y,z,w)=1$, and hence the gradient of $f$ will be orthogonal to this surface.  The gradient is given by $$\nabla f(x,y,z,w) = \left( \begin{array}{c} 2x\\ 2y \\ 2z \\ 2w \end{array}\right)$$ and evaluating this gradient at the point in question yields a vector orthogonal to the sphere at that point.  The set of all vectors orthogonal to this gradient is precisely the vectors $(a, b, c, 0)^T$.

Comment: The question you raise directly is answered simply by the words *chain rule* (this computation occurs in $\Bbb R^4$, but it's still the one-variable chain rule). The fact that the curve is at the point $(0,0,0,1)$ at $t=0$ tells you the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is an hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the submerion $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, such that $M=\{x:f(x)=0\}$, for every $x\in M, T_xM=\{x:df_x(v)=0\}$, apply this to $f(x)=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2-1$.